# How print user name after login in Laravel 6.4.1?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

please help me.
I use laravel 6.4.1 and i want to print user name after login
I try in header

```
@if(Auth::check())
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i><span>{{Auth::user()->username}</span></a>
                </li>
                @else
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i><span>fsfs</span></a>
                </li>
                @endif
```

My controller

```
public function postDangnhapAdmin(Request $req)
    {
        $this->validate($req,
        [
            'email'=>'required',
            'password'=>'required|min:3|max:6'
        ],[
            'email.required'=>'Banj das',
            'password.required'=>'sd',
            'password.min'=>'sds',
            'password.max'=>'sdsad'
        ]);
        if (Auth::attempt(['email'=>$req->email,'password'=>$req->password]))
        {
            return redirect()->intended('admin/yeye');
        }
        else{
        return redirect()->back()->with('ok','Tài khoản hoặc mật khẩu sai nhé');
    }
    }
```

It still return ('admin/yeye') but not print username.
Thanks

Comment: does the `users` table, or what ever you are using for auth, have a `username` column?

Answer (score 2):

You have typo in your code. check the following

```
 <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i><span>{{Auth::user()->username}</span></a>
```

On above line of your view file, instead of this

```
{{Auth::user()->username}
```

use this:

```
{{Auth::user()->username}}
```

Comment: @Modric  `{{ ... }`, missing a `}`

Comment: @Modric check the anchor tag in your first li where you trying to print username of logged in user.

Comment: @Modric what would be random about it? what is displayed?

Comment: after login fsfs displayed, but i want to display username.